# Is there any CSS code to position the image as shown below but responsive to screen size as well?

Tags: html, css, image, positioning

[image: screenshot of image]

HTML code:

```
<div class="image-holder grey2">
        <img src="laptop.png" alt="laptop">
</div>
```

I have tried to put image in a div(.image_holder) with css :

```
.image-holder {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0px 150px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    height: 150px;
}
```

and this for the image:

```
.image-holder img {
    width: 55%;
    height: auto;
    min-width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top:40px;
}
```

While resizing screen dark blue background gets either too big or narrow.

Comment: make a reproducible example, pls

Comment: add html structure as well for better explanation.

Comment: You can `vw` or `vh` for the height property of the image holder and the image. Adjust those according to your needs.

Comment: background-size: cover is probably your best bet here. Browser calculates the image and the available space and fills all the space available. You just have to sort how to create a div with that background that's the size of the viewport (either CSS or JS).